# dpkg-shlibdeps warning in Debian packaging with C++ virtual interfaces

Tags: c++, debian, packaging, deb

I have a C++ project that I am packaging for Debian. I make use of C++ pure virtual classes, and I believe this is contributing to `dpkg-shlibdeps` not finding out about dependencies correctly.

I have two libraries `libA` and `libB` built as separate Debian packages. In CMake `libB` is built specifying a dependency on `libA`, which is correct. However, I get the following warnings when building the packages:

```
dpkg-shlibdeps: warning: package could avoid a useless dependency if debian/libB/usr/lib/libB.so.1.0.0 was not linked against libA.so.1 (it uses none of the library's symbols)
```

The issue I suspect is that since `libB` uses `libA` through a pure virtual C++ class header, that it does not find the symbol for the concrete class implementation in `libA` and then concludes that no dependency really exists.

I'm wondering what steps I should take to resolve this warning?

I could imagine that there are solutions at the Debian packaging level, CMake build level, or perhaps at the code level.